# key up function not working on CKEditor 4

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4 but when I am applying `keyup` event to it, it's not working. The code is:

*HTML code:*

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="wc" id="wcso"></div>
    <div id="storyOutlineCircle1" class="badge badge-success round storyOutlineCircleClass" style="position: absolute;right:30px;bottom:0px;">100</div>
    <textarea id="storyOutline" rows="5" class="form-control" name="labinputstory" placeholder="Story Outline" required></textarea>
</div>
```

*JS code:*

```
<script>
       var e = CKEditor.instances['labinputstory']
       e.on( 'keyup', function( event ) {
           alert( e.getData() );
       });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor has only a [key event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#event-key). If you wish to use `keyUp`, you need to attach it to editor's `editable` like so:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', { /*editor instance configuration goes here*/ });
editor.on( "pluginsLoaded", function( event ){              
    editor.on( 'contentDom', function( evt ) {
        var editable = editor.editable();                   
        editable.attachListener( editable, 'keyup', function( e ) { 
            var keyCode = e.data.getKeystroke();
            // if ( keyCode == ... )
        });
    }); 
});
```